# Bash: getopts - ignoring option?

Tags: bash, getopts

Have some script with `getopts`. It includes next:

```
while getopts "hlcpx:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    h)
      usage && exit 1
      ;;
    l)
      last=1
      current=""
      ;;
    c)
      current=1
      last=""
      ;;
    p)
      prints=1
      exports=""
      ;;
    x)
      exports=1
      prints=""
      ;;
    \?)
      usage && exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "Using: current=$current last=$last prints=$prints exports=$exports"
```

But - when I run it with options `-x` and `-c` I got:

```
$ ./version.sh -x -l
Using: current= last= prints= exports=1

$ ./version.sh -x -c
Using: current= last= prints= exports=1
```

If I remove `:` - it works correctly:

```
$ cat version.sh | grep whil
while getopts "hlcpx" opt; do

$ ./version.sh -x -c
Using: current=1 last= prints= exports=1

$ ./version.sh -x -l
Using: current= last=1 prints= exports=1
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getopts` works as designed. If you don't need to pass a parameter to the `-x` option, don't append `:` to `x` in the `getopts` option string.

Alternatively, use your script with the expected syntax, eg:

```
./version.sh -x foo -c
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm idiot :D I'm really doesn't need require $OPTARG at all.